# How does LayoutParams.addRule work?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, layoutparams

I am building an application that will add views to a relative layout until stopped.
My question is how does RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.addRule work? If I keep calling addRule will this create an ever growing list or does addRule check if a rule already exists? Is the following code really neccessary? Can I just use addRule and if already exists this will not create a duplicate entry?

Thanks

```
    int[] rules = this.position[0].params.getRules();
    boolean rule = false;

    switch(index){
    case 0:

        for(int i = 0; i < rules.length; i++){
            if(rules[i]==RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF)
                rule = true;
        }

        if(!rule){
            this.position[0].params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF);
        }

        break;
    case 1:

        for(int i = 0; i < rules.length; i++){
            if(rules[i]==RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF)
                rule = true;
        }

        if(!rule){
            this.position[1].params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF);
        }

        break;
    case 2:

        for(int i = 0; i < rules.length; i++){
            if(rules[i]==RelativeLayout.ABOVE)
                rule = true;
        }

        if(!rule){
            this.position[2].params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE);
        }

        break;
    case 3:

        for(int i = 0; i < rules.length; i++){
            if(rules[i]==RelativeLayout.BELOW)
                rule = true;
        }

        if(!rule){
            this.position[3].params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);
        }

        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the code for the [`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/widget/RelativeLayout.java#RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) class you can see that the rules are stored in an `int` array where the rules are the indexes, so the rules will be added only once no matter how many times you call `addRule`(the last call will count).